# find all months by mktime

Tags: php, mysql, date, mktime

I can select all records of recent month from database using,

```
$month = (mktime(0,0,0,date('n'),1)); 
$q="SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp>$month";
```

This query will generate August's(recent month) records. 
I have to select all records of each month(January/February../July).

How can I select all other month's details?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't that... just be everything?

Comment: tip : if `timestamp` is your column name then wrap it with `

Comment: I need records month by month. If I click January, all records of January2012 need to display.

Comment: what is the datatype of the column which store the date

Comment: data type is "int" but it's storing timestamp (time()).

Comment: means it store timestamp value. am i getting you right?

Comment: yes. I have a column called "timestamp" It's datatype is "int". this column always store a timestamp value.

Comment: see my updated answer.hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**safety tips :** change the column name bcoz **timestamp** is mySQL reserve keyword and it  will lead to confusion , otherwise always use `` ` `` with column name.

i asuume  that dateColumn  datatype is **datetime**

```
<select name ="month" >
 <option value="1"> January </option>
 ...
</select>
```

now get the value of selected Month

```
$month = $_POST['month']; // means integer value of month ( 1,2,3..12)
```

then try with mySQL [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE MONTH(`dateColumn` ) = $month
```

### edit

if you store **timestamp** value in dateColumn then use this

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`dateColumn`)) = $month
```